# Share Desktop folders between admin and managed accounts?

Tags: macos, sharing, user-account, parental-controls

I'm thinking of trying to minimize distractions while doing homework by locking myself in an account managed by self-inflicted parental controls. My problem is, I don't want to not have access to my school files while I'm in the admin account. How can I give both accounts access to my school folders while keeping the convenience of having them on both accounts' desktops? (i.e. I'd very much like to not go to the Public folder every single time.)

Early 2011 MBP, OS X 10.10.1.

EDIT: Also a viable option, if anyone knows how to make it happen: A way to turn self-inflicted parental controls on and off at will despite being an admin.

Answer (score 1):

From the either account but preferably the admin account ( I will assume you are in the Admin account) you can go to the **users** folders.

**Part 1,**

Select the the managed account home folder.
use <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> to get the info panel for the folder.

At the bottom you will see the allowed access to the folder.

This should show **read & writ**e for that user, and no access for everyone.

Click the padlock and enter your admin details.

Now click the + button and either choose your Admin account name.
The admin account should now be added to the list.

Now change its access to read & write.

You should now from the Admin account be able to open the managed user account's folder but not any folder inside.

You now have a choice.  Depending on what you want.

**Part 2**
If for example you want only to access the Documents folder and all the files and folders enclosed. Then repeat the process above **Part 1** for the documents folder.

But this time, in the info panel for the documents folder, after you have completed the above **Part 1** on it. You will see a action button (Cog) at the bottom of the panel below the list.
Click the button and then the `Apply to enclosing items…`

When you confirm, all the items in Documents folder will replicate the access given to the Documents folder.

Or you can do the above by drilling down to only the folders you are interested in using **Part 1** and the final folder in that chain**Part 1** & **Part 2**

Or of cause you can just do chain**Part 1** & **Part 2** on the home folder.

But I personally would just do the folders I need.